# I need suggestions for a solid jQuery/CSS select box plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm currently working on a project that's using the Dropkick.js plugin to style select boxes. One issue that we're running into is that dropkick, while it looks nice, simply doesn't mirror the methods, properties and events of a select box.

I've had to write a lot of extra code to disable/enable selects, get and set values and a number of other things to just get the selects to play nice with the rest of the site and interact with other form elements.

So we switched over to test selectBox. Fantasic plugin with one exception: If you remove/add selects o the page via ajax and jQuery, it destroys the settings on every select in the page. This results in unuseable selects and JS errors all over the place. Since we're doing a lot of dynamic content, this won't work either.

Is there a GOOD select plugin out there that exposes all the methods and properties of a select box, can be styled nicely, AND works with dynamic content?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure about selectBox destroying the settings on every select? I used selectBox on a project recently that was dynamically adding select elements depending on previous selections and never had that kind of problem. Maybe there's something wrong in your code?

Comment: The problem isn't in adding selects, but removing them. This is for a veterinarian website, so if you select your pet type (cat/dog) it may add a select for weight ranges.

If you change the pet type, it'll remove the select or content that was just added, then load the content into the page. After that, none of the selects work - I get an error "settings is undefined" right around line 496 o the unminified selectBox.js.

Not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few options I know of (in no particular order):

#### StyleSelect

[Website](http://wellstyled.com/en/javascript-styleselect-jquery-plugin/)

Wraps the existing `<select>` tag, so all the events, properties and so on should remain accessible. The default styling isn't that nice though, and there are limits to how much it can be customised.

#### Chosen

[Website](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) - [Github](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen)

Nice default styling, but the generated markup is kind of weird and it doesn't support the whole range of callbacks you might need (only `change`)

#### jQuery UI Selectbox

[Website](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) - [Github](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui)

A good option if you are already using jQuery UI - otherwise potentially too much overhead. It doesn't use the `<select>`'s events, but has equivalent callbacks (and even ones not present on a regular submit, like `open`/`close`). Also it's [ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties) compliant.

#### jStyling

[Website](http://inspirativ.com/jstyling/) - [Github](https://github.com/polsad/jStyling)

Again, wraps the original `<select>` tag. Supports `disabled` options. Default styling is fairly uninspiring and it's designed to cover more than just select boxes (potentially unwanted cruft).

#### Uniform

[Website](http://uniformjs.com/) - [Github](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform)

Simple to implement, supports multiple themes. Lack of callbacks though, sometimes have to force `update` elements (mentioned already), covers more than just select boxes (again, potentially unwanted cruft).

Answer (score 3):

[Uniform](http://uniformjs.com) works well in my experience. If you update values dynamically, you have to call an update function, but that is easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform looks cool!

I've seen a similar method here: http://www.verot.net/jquery_select_skin.htm

It just hides the select box using opacity, and overlays a div that you can style

Answer (score 1):

I recently released [SelectBoxIt](http://www.selectboxit.com). It is jam packed with features so check it out.

**SelectBoxIt** Notable Features:

- Styleable with the jQueryUI Themeroller (optional)
- Supports all jQuery and jQueryUI show/hide effects (optional)
- Supports all jQueryUI/custom icons
- Includes ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications) support
- Full keyboard search and navigation support
- An event API triggered on the original select box element that calls the plugin
- A method API providing methods to interact with the dropdown list (i.e. Search, Open, Disable, Set Options).
- Passes jsHint with no errors
- Selected, Disabled, and Optgroup Support
- Easily extendable to allow developers to create new widgets